# Power event caused read-only disk

Tags: mount, fstab, disk

Having regained access to the server, my services won't come up due to a read only filesystem...

I've attempted a few steps on other articles to no avail, specifically

`sudo fsck -Af -M`, `mount -o remount /` and multiple reboots but it keeps coming up read-only.

Other articles suggested looking for and modifying RO in fstab but that doesn't appear to be present

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1abb791b-2288-4a86-a9a0-0b0dd184717d none swap sw 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/80a44c67-b3be-402c-9ce5-ea6f862e2fbf / ext4 defaults 0 0
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/50c99f9c-4bcb-459b-a2ca-488ae606356e /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Any other tricks to save this server? There's a state sensitive application on here I fear for.

Comment: If you do this search in Ask Ubuntu for *what causes a read only file system* you will see there are a lot of questions about the same thing. Maybe one of them can help you.

Answer (score 2):

resolved it finally with the right `fsck`

`fsck -f /dev/sda4` ran through corrections and prompted for reboot, system came up operational